Ag Grid: custom cellEditor not calling valueGetter or onCellValueChanged
I am introducing a custom cell editor that can wrap around itself. However I once i introduce this component it does not call:
the valueSetter
the onCellValueChanged event listenre
and the onKeyDown inside the custom cell editor is also not registering the Enter key.
Here are the components. Could somebody help? I tried many different methods from the props built in methods to even chat gpt a solution.
// src/components/FlashcardTable/FlashcardTable.js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import { addRow, updateContent, selectCell } from 'src/store/features/decks/deckSlice';
import CustomTextEditor from 'src/components/FlashcardTable/CustomTextEditor';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

const FlashcardTable = React.forwardRef(({ deckId }, ref) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const gridApi = useRef(null);
  const columnApi = useRef(null);
  const rowData = useSelector((state) => {
    const deck = state.decks[id];
    return deck ? deck.rows : [];
  });

  const columnDefs = [
    { headerName: '#', field: 'index', valueGetter: 'node.rowIndex + 1', width: 50, editable: false },
    {
      headerName: 'Question',
      flex: 2,
      field: 'question',
      editable: true,
      cellEditor: CustomTextEditor,
      valueSetter: (params) => {
        dispatch(updateContent({ id: deckId, rowIndex: params.node.rowIndex, field: 'question', content: params.newValue }));
        return true;
      }
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Answer',
      flex: 2,
      field: 'answer',
      editable: true,
      cellEditor: CustomTextEditor,
      valueSetter: (params) => {
        dispatch(updateContent({ id: deckId, rowIndex: params.node.rowIndex, field: 'answer', content: params.newValue }));
        return true;
      }
    },
  ];

  const onCellValueChanged = async (event) => {
    console.log('onCellValueChanged', event.rowIndex, event.column.getId());
    const lastRow = rowData[rowData.length - 1];
    if (lastRow && (lastRow.question.length > 0 || lastRow.answer.length > 0 || lastRow.topic)) {
      await dispatch(addRow({ id: deckId, row: { question: '', answer: '', topic: '' } }));
    }
      // Focus on the selected cell
      const { rowIndex, column } = event;
      const colIndex = columnApi.current.getAllGridColumns().findIndex(col => col.getColId() === column.getColId());
  
      let nextRowIndex = rowIndex;
      let nextColIndex = colIndex + 1;
  
      if (nextColIndex >= columnDefs.length) {
        nextRowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
        nextColIndex = 0;
      }
  
      const nextColumn = columnApi.current.getAllGridColumns()[nextColIndex];
      setTimeout(() => {
        gridApi.current.setFocusedCell(nextRowIndex, nextColumn.getColId());
        gridApi.current.startEditingCell({ rowIndex: nextRowIndex, colKey: nextColumn.getColId() });
      });
  };

  const onCellClicked = (event) => {
    console.log('onCellClicked',  event.rowIndex, event.column.getId())
    if (event.colDef.editable) {
      const { rowIndex, column } = event;
      dispatch(selectCell({ id: deckId, rowIndex, colId: column.getId() }));
    }
  };

  const onGridReady = (params) => {
    gridApi.current = params.api;
    columnApi.current = params.columnApi;
  };

  const defaultColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    editable: true,
    cellDataType: false,
    sortable: false,
    autoHeight: true,
    wrapText: true,
  };

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <AgGridReact
        ref={ref}
        rowData={rowData}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        onGridReady={onGridReady}
        onCellValueChanged={onCellValueChanged}
        onCellClicked={onCellClicked}
        domLayout="autoHeight"
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        rowSelection="single"
      />
    </div>
  );
});

export default FlashcardTable;


import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const CustomTextEditor = (props) => {
    console.log('props', props)

  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const minHeight = 40;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
      inputRef.current.value = props.value;
      updateRowHeight();
      console.log('Initial value:', inputRef.current.value);
    }
  }, [props.value]);

  const updateRowHeight = () => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      const rowHeight = Math.max(inputRef.current.scrollHeight, minHeight);
      props.api.rowModel.getRow(props.rowIndex).setRowHeight(rowHeight);
      props.api.onRowHeightChanged();
    }
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.stopPropagation();
      props.stopEditing();
      console.log('Final value on Enter:', inputRef.current.value);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = () => {
    updateRowHeight();
    props.colDef.valueSetter()
  };

  return (
    <textarea
      ref={inputRef}
      className="ag-input-field-input ag-text-field-input"
      style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap', overflow: 'hidden', resize: 'none', minHeight: `${minHeight}px` }}
      onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      onBlur={() => props.stopEditing()}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomTextEditor;

I tried the built in methods of the props inside the cellEditor custom components but no luck there. I tried to add event listeners and add cellEditorParams but also no luck there.
